# ClassName.class.getResource() returns null

Tags: java, embedded-resource

I’m trying to solve this problem for about 2 days. I’ve to create runnable JAR. I’m using Eclipse (newest version), Java SE 10 on macOS Sierra.

So, this is the only class in the test project.

```
package test_package;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedImage testImage = ImageIO.read(Tester.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/test.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is test project file structure (without test.jpg file):

```
TestProject

    - bin
    -- test_package
    --- Tester.class
    - src
    -- test_package
    --- Tester.java
```

I tried four different options:

```
BufferedImage testImage = ImageIO.read(Tester.class.getResourceAsStream("test.jpg"));

BufferedImage testImage = ImageIO.read(Tester.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.jpg"));

BufferedImage testImage = ImageIO.read(Tester.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/test.jpg"));

BufferedImage testImage = ImageIO.read(Tester.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.jpg"));
```

If test.jpg was placed in the root of the project, in src or test_package directory, the compiler always throwing the same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
```

If I copy test.jpg to bin directory, this two options give the correct result:

```
BufferedImage testImage = ImageIO.read(Tester.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.jpg"));

BufferedImage testImage = ImageIO.read(Tester.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.jpg"));
```

But when I am trying to create Runnable JAR, the same error appears. When trying to create JAR, I copied test.jpg to each directory of the project. 
I also tried to change option in Eclipse  Library handling when creating Runnable JAR (I tried all three options for the project with all four command options). In each case the error appears.

About the Source directory. In my case, the source directory is src.

So, I don’t know what to do next. I tried almost everything with no result. Any ideas?

Comment: the jpeg should be in the resources directory

Comment: where the test.jpg is located

Comment: I tried to locate it in each folder of the project.

Comment: Where exactly is the resource *in the JAR file?*

Comment: **One** problem is that this code is trying to get the resource in the main method and will therefore likely get the bootstrap class loader instead of the context class loader (meant for application resources). Make a constructor for the class and try it again from a method of the class in the form **`this.getClassLoader()..`**. Use the leading slash is that makes the path independent of the package of the class.

Comment: I tried this. There is no getClassLoader() method in the Object class, so I tried getClass().getClassLoader(). The errors are the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
Optional<InputStream> resourceAsStream = Optional
           .of(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                    "/test.jpg"));
```

Try this to get a stream then it can be converted to image

Comment: I tested it with test.jpg in src, root (no result) and bin (successfully). But when create JAR, I get NullPointerException in this case.